# How to close a pop up list view after selecting an item in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

Trying to close a list view after I click on an item. The `listview` pops up with a list of items and after i click on an item, it stays there. Is there a sort of similar thing to `dialog.dismiss()` or something for `listviews`?

```
     final ListView lvUser = new ListView(this);
    userList = tmDB.getAllUsers();
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.selectUser);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userList);
    lvUser.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    builder.setView(lvUser);

    //when user selects item
    lvUser.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String name = userList.get(position);
            int userID;
            userID = tmDB.getUserId(name);
            txtName.setText(name);
// close the list view after selecting an item
        }
    });
```

Comment: have you tried to dismiss dialog on listView click??

Comment: see my updated post it will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use like

```
 public AlertDialog alertDialog;

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.selectUser);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main3Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userList);
        lvUser.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        builder.setView(lvUser);

        //when user selects item
        lvUser.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String name = userList.get(position);
                int userID;
                userID = tmDB.getUserId(name);
                txtName.setText(name);
// close the list view after selecting an item
                alertDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You created Alert Dialog and Alert.dismiss()

```
 final AlertDialog.Builder builder;
 AlertDialog alert;
 final ListView lvUser = new ListView(this);
 userList = tmDB.getAllUsers();
 builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 builder.setTitle(R.string.selectUser);
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userList);
 lvUser.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
 //when user selects item
 lvUser.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String name = userList.get(position);
        int userID;
        userID = tmDB.getUserId(name);
        txtName.setText(name);
    // This!!
    if(alert != null){
        alert.dismiss();
    }
    }
 });
 builder.setView(lvUser);
 alert = builder.create
 alert.show();
```

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder is not contain a dismiss method

Comment: Edit Code. Alert Create and This Alert dismiss()

Answer (score 0):

AlertDialog.Builder have two builder.setPositiveButton and builder.setNegativeButton() methods to use it. Or you need to use simple Dialog for custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Using AlertDialog instance you can dismiss the pop up, you can not achieve by AlertDialog.Builder

final AlertDialog dialog;
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginScreen.this);
                alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
                alertDialog.setTitle("LIST OF DAYS");

```
            ListView listView = new ListView(getApplicationContext());
            final String[] listOfDays = {"MONDAY","TUESDAY","WEDNESDAY","THURSDAY","FRIDAY","SATURDAY","SUNDAY"};
            final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(LoginScreen.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listOfDays);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            alertDialog.setView(listView);

            dialog = alertDialog.create();

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this,arrayAdapter.getItem(position)+" CLICKED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
```